# Choosing parameters for testing

Tags: neural-network, image-classification, cnn, feature-scaling

I have a DL4J project [DL4J Framework](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/tree/master/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/convolution) for a CNN for Classification and Scaling. (Separate projects). My question is that how can I tune my parameters to achieve my goal?
Note that my question is general-purpose and not related to framework or the problem.

How can I approach tuning parameters for CNNs? I know you need to really know the field of machine learning but I would like to know the approach (even if it means throwing me some reading material) in order to execute a Deep Learning model.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to enumerate the hyperparameters. Then use grid search and cross validation to find the best combination of values.